# Optimizing Python code for quantizing sequence of floats

Tags: python, optimization

I want to mimic the process of digitizing an analog signal and so I'm writing code to take a random array of floats and convert them to an array of integers with a certain bit depth.

I have code that gets the job done, but the problem is that it's very slow and costly and I figure there's a much better way to do this. I'm currently creating the bins for a certain bit depth and then simply going through my list of floats, seeing which bin they fit into, and then creating a dictionary that maps that float to the integer value. Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np


def quantize_float(list_of_floats, bit_depth):

    MIN_VALUE = np.min(list_of_floats)
    MAX_VALUE = np.max(list_of_floats)
    NO_BINS = 2**(bit_depth) + 1

    _, bin_val = np.histogram(list_of_floats, NO_BINS-1, range=(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE))

    bin_val = bin_val.tolist()
    mapping = dict()

    for i in list_of_floats:
        mins = []
        for j in bin_val:
            mins.append(abs(j-i))

        #bin_ = bin_val.index(min(bin_val, key = lambda x:abs(x-i)))
        bin_ = mins.index(min(mins))
        mapping[str(i)] = bin_

    return mapping
```

Things seem fine for bit depths of 4 or 8, but I have to stop execution before it eats my computer's memory at bit depths of 24 or greater.

Comment: Why not simply round the samples to the nearest integer (probably after scaling to the appropriate range for the desired bit depth)?

Comment: Indeed, rounding to integers and then using `numpy.unique` or the like seems a good idea to avoid overusing memory here. See this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208899/sparse-3d-binning-histogram-function for discussion of sparse histograms in python.